# Find and replace in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a data in a string `tempType.tempcode` as shown below. At many place there are URLs pointing like this:

```
href=\"./assets/sources/template/....."
```

My requirement is I want to write a function which replaces all the `./assets/sources/template` to `sources/template`.

```js
    tempType.tempcode = < !DOCTYPE html > < html lang = "en" > < head > < meta charset = "utf-8" > < meta http - equiv = "X-UA-Compatible"
    content = "IE=edge" > < meta name = "viewport"
    content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" > < meta name = "description"
    content = "" > < meta name = "author"
    content = "" > {
        {
            META
        }
    } < link rel = "stylesheet"
    href = "./assets/sources/template/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    type = "text/css" > < link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins"
    rel = "stylesheet" > < link href = 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800'
    rel = 'stylesheet'
    type = 'text/css' > < link href = 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic'
    rel = 'stylesheet'
    type = 'text/css' > < link rel = "stylesheet"
    href = "./assets/sources/template/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    type = "text/css" > < link rel = "stylesheet"
    href = "./assets/sources/template/css/animate.min.css"
    type = "text/css" > < link rel = "stylesheet"
    href = "./assets/sources/template/css/light-slider.css"
    type = "text/css" > < link rel = "stylesheet"
    href = "./assets/sources/template/css/style.css"
    type = "text/css" > < link rel = "stylesheet"
    href = "./assets/sources/template/css/common.css"
    type = "text/css" > < /head>  <body id="page-top">      <div id="main-wrapper">           {{CONTENT}}       </div > <!-- jQuery -->     <script src="./assets/sources/template/js/jquery.js"></script>      <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->     <script src="./assets/sources/template/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->     <script src="./assets/sources/template/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>     <script src="./assets/sources/template/js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>     <script src="./assets/sources/template/js/wow.min.js"></script>  <script src="./assets/sources/template/js/popupimage.js"></script>     <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->    <script src="./assets/sources/template/js/creative.js"></script>  <script src="./assets/sources/template/js/light-slider.js"></script> <script src="./assets/sources/template/js/count.js"></script> <script src="./assets/sources/template/js/menu.js"></script>  <script src="./assets/sources/template/js/vertical_list.js"></script> <script src="./assets/sources/template/js/sticky.js"></script> <script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-One-Page-Navigation-Plugin-Page-Scroll-To-ID/jquery.malihu.PageScroll2id.js"></script> <script>  (function($){   $(window).load(function(){    $(".nav a").mPageScroll2id();                                                 $("#lightSlider").lightSlider();     callCounter();     callvertical_list();      $(".menu2").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });   });  })(jQuery); </script> </body>  </html>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular? By the way, it is really that hard to format your post properly?

Answer (score 1):

For each variable, you have to use a Regexp like so :

```
let pattern = '(./assets/sources/template)';
let regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');
let newString = yourVariable.replace(regex, 'sources/template');
```

Comment: But if it's only in your code, just do a search and replace in your IDE.